# PHP Soap method call not return all data but __getLastResponse does

Tags: php, soap, php-7.1

I am making a call to a method using php soap.

```
$options = ['trace' => 1,
            'exceptions' => true,
            'wsdl_cache' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE];

$wsdl = 'confidential-wsdl';
$client = new \SoapClient($wsdl,$options);

try {
    $result = $client->__call("SomeClientsMethod",array($params));
    $response = $client->__getLastResponse();
    var_dump($result); // Not all data received
    var_dump($response); // All data received
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //No exception thrown
    throw new \Exception("Request failed!".$client->__getLastResponse());
}
```

This call not returns all data which are defined in the wsdl,
but if i call $client->__getLastResponse(), then i receive all data correctly

Can someone put me in the right direction where to debug?
Thanks in advance

Calling method and wsdl are updated with additional data which i'm not receiving.

Comment: Have you started by wrapping it in a `try / catch`?

Comment: Sorry, i edited my question. Yes, i'm using try/catch but no exception thrown.
So, calling method was updated with those additional data which i'm not receiving. Maybe some cache issue? But i have option WSDL_CACHE_NONE

Answer (score 0):

To catch errors, try wrapping your calls in a [try/catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

```
try{
    $client = new \SoapClient($wsdl,$options);
    $client->__call("SomeClientsMethod",array($params));
}

# I'm not sure exactly which one of these it is:

catch(Throwable $e){
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
catch (SoapFault $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Same issue here. i have already used try catch wrapper. but seems not working

Answer (score 0):

it looks like this was a cache issue.
Probably because of soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400 option in php.ini
Now, call to a function returns all data...

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, php does the parser, and it returns only two elements

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2023-01-27T18:05:56.227Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2023-01-27T18:10:56.227Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <ListarSolicitacoesInscricaoMunicipalResponse xmlns="Jucesp.Services.InscricoesMunicipais.InscricaoMunicipal">
            <ListarSolicitacoesInscricaoMunicipalResult xmlns:a="Jucesp.Services.InscricoesMunicipais.InscricaoMunicipal/01" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <AuthenticationHeader i:nil="true" xmlns="Jucesp.Services.Viabilidades.Data/01" xmlns:b="Jucesp.Services.Data/01"/>
                <a:solicitacoes>
                    <a:solicitacao>
                        <a:protocoloRedesim>SPP2330004767</a:protocoloRedesim>
                        <a:cnpj>49364299000152</a:cnpj>
                        <a:numeroRegistro i:nil="true"/>
                        <a:nomeEmpresarial>OSMAR DE PAULA LIMA FILHO MINI MERCADO</a:nomeEmpresarial>
                        <a:dataSolicitacao>2023-01-27T13:18:35.103</a:dataSolicitacao>
                        <a:orgaoRegistro>Junta Comercial</a:orgaoRegistro>
                        <a:eventos>
                            <a:evento>
                                <a:Codigo>101</a:Codigo>
                                <a:Descricao>Inscrição de primeiro estabelecimento</a:Descricao>
                            </a:evento>
                        </a:eventos>
                        <a:situacao>Viabilidade Utilizada</a:situacao>
                    </a:solicitacao>
                </a:solicitacoes>
            </ListarSolicitacoesInscricaoMunicipalResult>
        </ListarSolicitacoesInscricaoMunicipalResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

[image]